# Mod Rewrite - ignore catalog before string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have simple rewriting for blog articles using this directive

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?aid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works as intended when using urls like

```
http://example.com/some-blog-title
```

Lately I added special category for some post and need it urls in form

```
http://example.com/categoryname/some-blog-title
```

So what I need is to use both types of url on site

```
http://example.com/some-blog-title
```

and

```
http://example.com/categoryname/some-blog-title
```

and both of them using viewpost.php?aid=$1 script. 
Categoryname is just a word (product name). It wont change so it doesnt need to be dynamic. I want to use it simply for seo purpose. 
So i need this directive to accept both types of url - with categoryname or without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your rule to this to make category name optional:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:[\w-]+/)?([\w-]+)/?$ viewpost.php?aid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That's what i needed. :) Thank you.